# Catching save event in Form Builder

Tags: orbeon, xbl

I would like to send submission after form has been saved in Form Builder, I was trying something like this at first (in my XBL file):

```
<xf:action ev:event="fr-data-save-done" ev:observer="fr-form-model">
    <xf:message event="#all" level="modal">Saved</xf:message>
    <xf:send submission="my-submission" ev:event="#all"/>
</xf:action>
```

The code above is placed in XBL file between xbl:template, outside xbl:model (though I tried to put it inside xbl:model with no luck).
Unfortunately it's not working, after I save my form in Form Builder message is not shown.
Anyone got idea why it's not working?

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: It is currently just between xbl:template. I tried to move it inside xbl:model but it didn't help.

Comment: Also the question is : does it matter which Orbeon version do I use ? It's not working under Orbeon 4.7 but maybe it would under 4.5 ?

Comment: I don't think it should work with either version. Components encapsulate functionality, and so listening to the `fr-data-save-done` event`, which is external to the component, should not work. Ideally, your component and Form Builder should be "glued" together with events, for example: external event handler dispatching a custom event to your component, for example.

Comment: Well it doesn't sound like easy for me, could you be more specific when talking about 'external event handler' or maybe there are some examples where something similar is done ? Do I understsand correctly that it is not possible to achive sending submission on save form based only on my XBL file ? Merry Christmas, I think it's great what you are doing with Orbeon and here helping out all those people - I really appreciate it

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Currently I don't think it is possible just with the XBL component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place by hand an event handler like this:

```
<foo:bar id="my-component-id" bind="my-bind">
    <xf:dispatch
        event="fr-data-save-done"
        observer="fr-form-model"
        name="my-custom-event"
        targetid="my-component-id"/>
</foo:bar>
```

The handler doesn't have to be within the element:

```
<foo:bar id="my-component-id" bind="my-bind"/>
<xf:dispatch
    event="fr-data-save-done"
    observer="fr-form-model"
    name="my-custom-event"
    targetid="my-component-id"/>
```

And inside the XBL component:

```
<xbl:binding id="my-binding-id" element="foo:bar">
    <xbl:handlers>
        <xbl:handler event="my-custom-event" phase="target">
            ... XForms actions here ...
        </xbl:handler>
    </xbl:handlers>
    ...
</xbl:binding>
```

Comment: Hey Erik, I've just realized that I am not able to make this work. I've created this example https://gist.github.com/anonymous/30ab64d3e7642e7860f0 and it's not working : after clicking on Save button in Form Builder the message is not shown. If I change event from "fr-data-save-done" to "#all" the message 'Working' is shown so there something wrong with this event apparently.

Comment: To be petfectly clear : when I change event to "#all" message is shown after I press Test and the message is not shown after clicking on Save. So it means that generally handler is working but there is some kind of problem with 'fr-data-save-done'.

Comment: If anything is still unclear I can explain more or I can try to create maybe better example if the one above is not good enough.

Comment: Ah, in Form Builder, that's another story! I missed it had to work in the builder. It is likely that something like this will break in the future because it depends too much on internals which can change. Instead, form builder has a [process](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Buttons-and-Processes) called [`oxf.fr.detail.process.save.orbeon.builder`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/49aa6d2099b1c78e4286f0395c15d997e12cde6c/src/resources-packaged/config/properties-form-builder.xml#L113). You could overwrite that process to add your own behavior.

Comment: Thank you for response. Yeah, I know I could use processes, I've read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797037/orbeon-send-button-with-parameters/27825878#27825878 but I use Orbeon 4.5 and was hoping I could achive what I want and not have to update Orbeon to newer version. So to make things clear : you think it's not possible to catch save action (send submission after save, whatever) in Orbeon 4.5 ?

Comment: I am not sure it is absolutely impossible. In theory events dispatched at the Form Builder level are meant to be hidden to the form being edited. But if it is possible, I suspect the solution will be very brittle.