# Event xforms-model-construct-done behaviour

Tags: forms, orbeon, xbl

In my form I would like to call web service after to form is loaded after publishing. I've created custom XBL control for it, where I have :

```
<xf:group id="component-group">
    <xf:action ev:event="xforms-enabled" ev:target="component-group">
        <xf:send ev:event="xforms-enabled" submission="my-submission"/> 
    </xf:action>
</xf:group>
```

But it doesn't work as expected : my submission is sent everytime when I add new element in FormBuilder or change a name of some other controls. Generally speaking submission is sent when my form is changing in some way.

Now I want submission to be sent ONLY when I publish my form and someone would open it to fill (and of course when I press "Test" in FormBuilder, but I guess it's the same as filling form after publishing).

I was trying something like this :

```
<xf:group id="component-group">
    <xf:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done" ev:target="component-group">
        <xf:send ev:event="xforms-model-construct-done" submission="my-submission"/> 
    </xf:action> 
</xf:group>
```

Unfortunately it's not working, this way submission is not sent at all. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that XBL components are *live* at design time too. So you need a way to test whether the component is running within Form Builder or not.

There should be a function for this, really, but there isn't (I added this to the list of functions we should add to the API [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1095)). You can do:

`<xf:group id="component-group">
    <xf:var name="fr-params" value="xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')"/>
    <xf:action 
        event="xforms-enabled"
        target="component-group"
        if="not($fr-params/app = 'orbeon' and $fr-params/form = 'builder')">
        <xf:send submission="my-submission"/> 
    </xf:action>
</xf:group>`

A few minor comments:

- you don't need to (in fact shouldn't) place `event` attributes on nested actions
- you don't even need the `ev` prefix

Comment: Thank you for your answer, works as always. If you have some time to spare it would be great if you could look at my other problem, which is catching event on save button in Form Builder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608979/catching-save-event-in-formbuilder . I have a code which I believe should work, but I guess there is a little mistake somewhere