# Orbeon Send Button With Parameters

Tags: parameters, orbeon

I have looked for a while and cant find a solution that allows me to send request parameters from my forms to an external webapp when I press the save-final button.

This is what I have so far in my properties-local.xml...

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.*.*"
value="http://localhost:8080/monnieapp/?id={xxf:get-request-parameter('doc-id')}"/>

<property
as="xs:string"
name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-final.*.*"
value='require-uploads
         then require-valid
         then save
         then send(property = "oxf.fr.detail.send.success", uri = "http://localhost:8080/monnieapp/")
         then success-message("save-success")
         recover error-message("database-error")'/>
```

I have tried changing values and property names etc but I keep getting the following message when I try to save...

```
An error has occurred while processing the request.
```

Any advice on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 4.7.0, try 4.7.1, [this issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1972) was fixed. With 4.7.1, the following should work:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-final.*.*">
    require-uploads
    then require-valid
    then save
    then send(uri = "http://localhost:8080/monnieapp/?id={xxf:get-request-parameter('doc-id')}")
    then success-message("save-success")
    recover error-message("database-error")
</property>
```

Comment: so I will need to wait on the next community release to be able to do this?

Comment: You can either [build from source](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Contributors-~-Building-Orbeon-Forms) from the `4.7-ce` branch, or wait for 4.8.0, which is coming out real soon.

Comment: @ebruchez - Can you please let me know, How can I post the data as `form parameter` to `external REST service` using `send`