# How to get form values on click of save button in orbeon

Tags: xml, scala, xhtml, orbeon

I have created a proxy portlet and deployed on life Ray portal, everything is working fine as expected. Now on click of save button I need get the form inputs and save it in db. As of now I haven't created a database layer for orbeon. On click of save button I need to hit the some url with inputs as parameters.. I have the following questions

1) Where will I get form inputs on click of save button(file name) ? 
2) can it possible to pass the form inputs to jsp or java page?
3) if I want to disable some buttons in form runner, how can I do that?  Any documentation that from where do I need to start for customization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.* property to choose buttons that    you want to show/hide.**

http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Buttons-on-the-detail-page

**To post to a external service, you should use 'send' button:**

```
       <property 
                 as="xs:string"        
              name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.testapp.testform" 
            value="save-draft send"/> 



        <property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.testapp.testform"
  value='require-valid
         then send("http://localhost:8081/context/yourservice")
         then navigate("/success")
         recover navigate("/failure")'/>
```

Note: Use `oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*` and `oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*` if you want it for all of your forms and apps.

The following links have information to help you to change the actions used for the buttons:

http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/04/more-powerful-buttons.html

https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Buttons-and-Processes

Comment: You have to place it in resources/config/properties-local.xml

Comment: I tried it, It is throwing errors. In what format the URL should be look like? Can you please update the code with some URL? Where is that send() is defined? How do I print the values before save? In which format the values are going to send/save? please describe it more this is my first project. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version are you using? If you added xf.fr.detail.buttons.*.* like my answer, you should be able to see 'Send' button on your forms. The URL depends on the service you are calling. And you do not need to define send(), it's implemented in Orbeon, adding it to your properties-local.xml should call your service.

Comment: If you are using version 4.7, change to version 4.8, since there was a bug in it related to version 4.7, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797037/orbeon-send-button-with-parameters

Comment: From the following code http://localhost:8080/monnieapp/?id={xxf:get-request-parameter('doc-id')}, here they are passing some parameters right there what does "doc-id" represents? and from where are they requesting the parameter? Can it possible to get value from the form input field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70054/discussion-between-inanda-menezes-and-precious).

Comment: @InandaMenezes - Could you please help in http://stackoverflow.com/q/39318179/2478134